# .htaccess Error : Invalid command 'AuthGroupFile'

Tags: 14.04, lamp, .htaccess

before this i was working on windows and my project was working proper. recently i moved to ubuntu and i am trying setup project on LAMP.

i have created host for this (windows i was running directly through localhost) and when i am running it getting 500 Internal server Error.

when i looked in my log file i got Invalid command 'AuthGroupFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

.htaccess File

```
#php_value zend.ze1_compatibility_mode off
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /opt/lampp/htdocs/uniplex_mobile/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 

<Files manageurls.html>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files addurl.html>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files editurl.html>
require valid-user
</Files>

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

my project is on smarty framework.

can anyone help to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can remove that directive

Comment: Which linux distributions are you using???

Comment: @AbdulKadir i am using 14.04

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773547/htaccess-error-invalid-command-authgroupfile

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try:

```
a2enmod authz_groupfile
```

This should help you.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, but it's need root permission with `sudo`, too.

Comment: You make my day. It works properly but as @Chu-SiangLai said, you need `sudo` command to get it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use `sudo` for this command as it worked for me:

```
sudo a2enmod authz_groupfile
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... ;-)